# Analyze PDF files to detect malicious ones

Tags: pdf, hash, output

I write a code in python that detect malicious PDF. 
every file I analyze I calculate its hash value and save it in hash database, besides saving the output in text file. 
If I want to scan another file I calculated it hash value then search it in hash database, if found I print the output from the text that is already exist.
but if the hash value is not exist it is saved and the output is saved in text file

I need help on how could I link between the hash value and the text that contain the output?

Comment: If you're using a database, why not just add another column for the text output.

Comment: no I want a simple way . I don't use database

Comment: Oh you said hash database so I assumed you were using a database. If its local files you're dealing with. Why not use a hashtable?

Comment: what is this ?? how could I use it ?? is it possible by it to link to text file like above ?

Comment: I suggest you start researching [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.python.org%2F2%2Ftutorial%2Fdatastructures.html&ei=YY-gU4ivN6HmsASPuoDABA&usg=AFQjCNFY76BRPBK7ad4NiU9AhhtIys6kJw&sig2=0cSiPdmzwWXl70P-fC2Lsg&bvm=bv.68911936,d.cWc). Your problem I believe could even be solved with a simple 2 dimensional array.

Comment: but I think every time I run the program the array is reset. am I coorect ??/

Comment: It is so you would need to save the array to a file or something and read it when the program restarts.

Comment: yes its doable thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Kyle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2138140/kyle) mentioned, you can use a hash table. A hash table is similar to a dictionary. In python I actually believe they're called dictionaries. For more on that, look here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm

As far as your question is concerned, you have a variety of options. You will have to save your 'database' at some point and you could save it in many different formats. You could save it as a JSON file (a very popular style). It could be an XML file (very popular as well). You could even save it as a CSV (not nearly as popular, but it gets the job done). For the sake of this, let's say you save this 'database' in a text file which looks like this:

`5a4730fc12097346fdf5589166c373d3{C:\PdfsOutput\FileName.txt}662ad9b45e0f30333a433566cee8988d{C:\PdfsOutput\SomeOtherFile.txt}`

Essentially you're formatting it as `HashValue{PathToFileOnDisk}...` You could then parse this via regex that looks like `[0-9a-f]{32}\{[^\}]+` Then you would scan your database on startup using this regex, load up all matches, iterate all matches, split each match at '{' and then put the `ValueSplit[0]` into a dictionary as the key with the path to that text file as the value for that key.

So, after you do the regex search, get your matches and are iterating them, within the iteration loop say something like:

`ValueSplit = RegexMatch.split('{')
HashAndFileDict[ValueSplit[0]] = ValueSplit[1]`

This code assumes the regex match in the loop is a string simply called 'RegexMatch'. It also assumes that your dictionary you're storing hash values and paths in is called 'HashAndFileDict'

Later in your code you can check a PDF hash value in question by saying:

`if(!HashAndFileDict.hash_key(PDFHashValue):
    TextFilePath = savePDFOutputText(ThePDFFile)
    HashAndFileDict[PDFHashValue] = TextFilePath
else:
    print("File already processed. Text is at: " + HashAndFileDict[PDFHashValue])`

---

If I may, it might be wise to use 2 hashing algorithms and combine their hexadecimal digests into 1 string in order to prevent a collision when processing many PDF files.